# Обработка событий WindowsMediaPlayer

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно обработать событие `PlayStateChange` у объекта `WindowsMediaPlayer`. 
Создаю обработчик:

```
using WMPLib;
///
///
private WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer;

wplayer.PlayStateChange += new _WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(PlayStateChange);

private void PlayStateChange( object sender, _WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e ) {
}
```

Но компилятор ругается:

> Error  1   No overload for 'PlayStateChange' matches delegate 'WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler'
>
> Error  2   The type or namespace name '_WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Вопрос, как мне обработать событие?

Comment: я уже плохо помню c#, но по-моему private вы обработчиком не запихаете.

Comment: А что говорит документация на `WMPLib` o `WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler`?

Comment: Fike, запихивается и с private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неожиданно нашел в интернете решение, с другой сигнатурой метода:

```
public void PlayStateChange( int NewState ) {

}
```